# How to predict, how much epochs model need?

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to colorize image using autoencoder and I have following model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 1024)        4719616   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 1024)        9438208   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         4719104   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 16, 16, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 32)      18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 256, 256, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 16)      4624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 2)       290       
=================================================================
Total params: 28,295,090
Trainable params: 28,295,090
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have also prepared dataset counting 80 000 images. 40 000 of people and 40 000 of nature.

My attempts:

100 EPOCHS:

[image: 100]

120 EPOCHS:

[image: 120]

160 EPOCHS:

[image: 160]

210 EPOCHS:

[image: 210]

300 EPOCHS:

[image]

I am using LAB color space and MAE as loss function.

How can i setup the most appropriate number of epochs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact answer to how many epochs is needed. It is important that the model must be not overfitted or under fitted with data. You can use L1 / L2 regularizers to avoid memorizing train dataset. On the other hand, you can use [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) to cut epochs when `loss` or `val_loss` is not dramatically changed.

Comment: First i had earlyStopping=25 => 100 epochs, earlyStopping=40 => 210 epochs. I will try regularizers.

Comment: What values do you use for early stopping? I recommend you to read articles about auto-encoders which people mention their models' details. Many things can change your results like `kernel initialization`, `dataset quality`, `optimizers`.. etc.. Model building is a research topic, you should experience different options and find best `hyperparameters` that define your model or dataset.

Comment: I used val_loss.